# Removing unexpected (and even unseen) spaces in google script ( regex help maybe?)

Tags: split, cell, space

On the sheet I'm working on as test, I really carefully set up answers so I can safely use split(', '). My data looks like "surname1 name1, surname2 name2, surname3 name3". So the split will return
[surname 1 name1,surname2 name 2,surname3 name3,....]

Yet, I don't know why sometimes it returns [surname1 name1, surname2 name2, surname3 name3, ]  (see the extra space in front of the surnames?). It is always the same answers that trigger this strange behavior.

I tried clearing formatting on the data sheet with no success.
I copied one of the string answer with this bad behavior into an other cell of the sheet, and the output was correct !

So i assumed that the behavior comes from the cell, or whatever. But I can't find a way to get around this error, yet alone prevent it in the future when I won't be testing anymore.

Is there a regex (I'm totally clueless on that), to split ', ' ie a comma and a space that I can try ?

OR, is there a way to specify a split(', #Anynumerofspaces') ?

many thanks in advance !

- clearing format of cells, and sheet  (no result)
- copying data into an other cell (working !)
- tried this morning trim() of the " surname name", without success